# Conformal map from $\Omega$ to the complex unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find a conformal map from $\Omega =\mathbb{C} \backslash \{ z = yi \in \mathbb{C} \vert |y| \geq 1, y \in \mathbb{R} \}$ to the complex unit disk.

I tried breaking it down to smaller steps, so first transforming $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{C} \backslash [0, + \infty]$ by using the map $z \mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i}$. I think this works because this maps the 'slits' onto the positive real line.

Then, if I could transform $\mathbb{C} \backslash [0, + \infty]$ to the upper half plane, I could use $z \mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ to transform the upper half plane to the complex unit disk. But I can't find how to do this.

And I don't know if this is the right approach?

Comment: You can easily show that your mapping is injective, by just looking at $\frac{z-i}{z+i} = \frac{u-i}{u+i}$.